# How to link my css, js and image file link in django

Tags: python, css, django

I am a newbie in Django 1.9.5 and using windows as my platform. I have a problem to link my css, images and js to django templage,

Here is my project structure

[image: Here is my setting.py page]

Here is my settings page

```
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)

    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    STATICFILES_DIRS = (
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'statics'),
    )


    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

[image: Here is my main url.py page]

Here is my main url.py page

```
    from django.conf import settings
    from django.conf.urls import include, url
    from django.conf.urls.static import static
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
        url(r'^mysite/', include('myapp.urls')),
        # (r'^media/(?P.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
        #  {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
        url(r'^media/(?P.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
    ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

[image: Here is my base html page located within template folder]

Here is my base html template

[image: Here is my base html template]

Github link [My project in github](https://github.com/manozbiswas/Djangoapp)
I have tried all possible combination but failed in 2 days.
Any help will be appropriated and I will be grateful to you
Thanks

Comment: please try formatting the code first , then only we can answer your queries..

Comment: Please see again , I have formatted my code

Comment: what the error shown on browser console?

Comment: It would have been better if you had posted the code itself instead of its images.

Comment: Please see again I have posted the necessary code, Thanks

Comment: @AvinashRaj, the error is not found my mysite/style.css. another one is I have got http://127.0.0.1:8000/mysite/static/style.css but the css does not work any more and the link not found

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
    {% load staticfiles %}

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'pathtostaticfile' %}" />
```

You can using statcfiles tag to load your static file.  With pathtostaticfile is your static file

More detail
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial06/

Comment: I had the same problem before, after I put the `css` file into the static folder then it worked.

Answer (score 2):

first of all add following code in

**urls.py**
use this library

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

add following code in 
**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS= [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'assets'),] # this variable have been created for  adding static resourcess
```

in template(html) file you will  first of all load

```
{% load static %}

<link rel="stylesheet" href=" {% static '/boostrap4.4/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href=" {% static '/fontawesome-free-5.12.1-web/css/all.css' %}">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href=" {% static '/css/style.css' %}">
```